# Unit test - custom class validation with entity manager

Tags: validation, testing, symfony, symfony-2.3

I am trying to test a custom validator which use the entity manager.

The validator is **working fine in the form**, but I'm still having problem testing it: **it never throw a violation**.

My validator is a **Class validator** but add a violation to the **field** Lastname `$this->context->addViolationAt('lastname',$message,$param);`

There is the code in My Test Class:

```
public function testNoMoreThreeBatman() {

  $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator();
 
  //I have already checked I got my test database ok, full with what I want
  
  //I create a new one with the name 'wayne' (so it'll be not valid)
  $user = new User();
  $user->setLastname('wayne');

  $violationList = $validator->validate($user);

  $this->assertEquals(1, $violationList->count());

}
```

I have found a lot of topics, but no one is giving me a hint. I have test with another custom validation, a simple one and I have no problem.
I'm wondering if the problem could come from the fact it's a class validator or the fact it add the violation to a field

Because my answer is in a comment, I post the response here for more visibility:

**Correct is** `Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator();`

**Instead of** `$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator();`

Comment: Hmmm.  Is your validator even being called?  I suspect not.  I'm assuming you mapped User to the validator in validation.yml?  If so then you need some more stuff to tie the validator to the config files.

Comment: How can I see if my validator is called? Yes, my validator is mapped in my validation.yml, and works fine when I use it in my form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while its really a functional test, I think you best bet would be to just grab the validator service:

```
class MyTest extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $validator = $client->getContainer()->get('validator');

        ...
```

=============================================================

**Can you explain the difference between calling static::get('validator') and Validation::createValidatorBuilder?**

In answer to your comment, I don't know where the static:get you are referring to comes from.  What base class are you using for your unit test?  But it does not really matter because I assume that static::get is accessing the dependency injection container.

So your question is really:  What is the difference between using the Symfony 2 container and the actual component itself?

The thing to understand is that when you start up a Symfony 2 app, all kinds of configuration files are read and all kind of things happen behind the scenes.  In particular, a service called validator is created and initialized by things such as validation.yml.  Likewise, your custom validator is created and is passed your entity manager as a dependency.

None of this happen when you just use Validation::createValidatorBuilder by itself.  No configuration, no mapping, no entity managers etc.  Take a look at the code to see what actually happens.  Take a look at the component documentation to see how to use it directly.  It's actually a worth while exercise to go through as it helps to understand just how Symfony wires everything up.

Comment: I can access to static::get('validator') instead of my Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator(); and it works fine! thanks a lot.

Can you explain the difference between calling static::get('validator') instead of $this->get('validator') or Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator();